# how to find out the selected row in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a project in .net with c#. in that there is a registration form of new users into the site. admin should approve the registration. for that I'm using a GridView. How to find out the selected row in the grid view?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`GridView.SelectedRow` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx).

Alternatively, you can get the index of the selected row with the [`GridView.SelectedIndex` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

are you perhaps referring to a DATAGRIDVIEW?

if so, to find the content of a certain column of the selected row

```
 datagridviewname.item(0, datagridviewname.currentrow.index).value
```

where 0 = first column of your datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Use following gridview property>

```
gvTradeFile.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) for this type of thing:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gvUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dateregistered" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkApprove" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userid") %>' Text="Approve"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkDeny" CommandName="Deny" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userid") %>' Text="Deny"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now you need to pass instructions through on RowCommand...

```
private void gvUsers_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Approve":
            // Executes code to update the users table,
            // setting the approved flag to true
            // Usage: ApproveUser(integer userid);
            ApproveUser(e.CommandArgument);
            break;
        case else:
            // do whatever if the user registration wasn't approved
            break;
    }
}
```

The switch is a good idea in case you need to do a few things with the data here. It evaluates the primary key value for the row (in this case, that's the value of the `userid` column in the database) for the selected row (automatically determined when you click the link) along with the CommandName to tell it what to do with that information.

Hope this helps.